# How to generate an url within a Silex controller

Tags: url, silex

I'd like to generate an url from a named route inside a controller method. There's no more urlGenerator in Silex 2.0. How can I do taht ?

```
class FormController {

    public function genForm(Application $app, Request $request){

        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
            ->setAction(/* HOW TO GENERATE 'home' ROUTE URL */)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Yes there is](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/RoutingServiceProvider.php#L48). It just that the docs has been reorganized. Check the [Service page](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/services.html#core-services).

So you should just call it as usual:

`$app['url_generator']->generate(
  'my-route-name', 
  ["some-parameter" => "some-value"]
);`

In your case:

```
class FormController {

    public function genForm(Application $app, Request $request){

        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
            ->setAction($app['url_generator']->generate('your-route-name'));
```

Comment: Is the problem already solved or not? Otherwise, please mark as completed!

Comment: Olivier, as @LexdeWilligen suggests, if my answer solved your problem you should accept it in order to mark the question closed. See SO help for [how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).